# Preview Image Url in tweepy V2

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I have been trying to get the "**preview_image_url**" from a users timeline of tweets. I have been using V2 and paginator to get all the tweets as API have limit of 100 tweets per request. I am not able to access the media_fields as it's not present or pops up using dir method as well in python. This is the code I am using right now. the code only provides the media key for a particular tweet.

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=my_keys.BEARER_TOKEN)

username_list =  ["coinfessions"]
user_id = client.get_user(username="coinfessions").data.id
print(user_id)

for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id= str(user_id), exclude=['retweets', 'replies'], expansions = "attachments.media_keys", media_fields = ["url","preview_image_url"],max_results=5 ).flatten(10): 
    if tweet.attachments is not None:
        print(tweet.attachments)
```

In one of the question posted on stack overflow. Someone suggested using the response as  the return type. This method includes a "include" key where you can find the type, media_key and preview_image_url. I tried this method and it worked fine with normal response. However, it's not working well with the paginator. I think, I am doing something wrong here.

Anothor response on similar question points to this official FAQ page on [tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.6.0/faq.html#how-do-i-access-includes-data-while-using-paginator). If anyone can help me in understanding, how to access [Models](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_models.html) in V2 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `includes` if you are using the `flatten` methods.

The only way to access them is to iterates through the responses themselves.

```py
paginator = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, [...])  # Without the flatten

for page in paginator:  # Each page is a response from the API
    page.data           # All the tweets in each page
    page.includes       # All the includes in each page
```

On a side note, I don't understand why you are using `max_results=5`. Because of that, you retrieve only 5 results per request and you cancel the advantages of the paginator.

Comment: I used max_results =5 just to test the data I am getting back from the API. How can I specify the total tweets I want back in this case?

Comment: @Tarster Use the `limit` parameter in combination with the `max_results` parameter. For example, `paginator = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, [...], max_results=100, limit=5)` will retrieve 5 pages of 100 tweets each (so a total of 500 tweets).